# PHP/MySQL Date and Time comparison (without seconds)

Tags: php, mysql

I created a DateTime Object with PHP and inserted it into the database column scheduled time - as this: `2017-03-13 07:30:00`

Now I want to run a query and select the rows which have the same time or the time is less than the current time - assuming the current time is `2017-03-13 08:30:00`. I want to ignore the seconds because those doesn't matter.

I do this:

```
SELECT * FROM fp_mail_reminder
        WHERE DATE_FORMAT(scheduledtime, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i') <= DATE_FORMAT('2017-03-13 08:30:00', '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i')
        AND active = 1
        ORDER BY id ASC
```

However the query does not result a row which has been inserted with 2017-03-13 07:30:00. If I change the date as this: 2017-03-12 07:30:00 - so I change the day, the result is coming up.

Can anybody say why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is comparing the **string values** instead of the actual date values. The problem here is that the string comparison of '21.01.2017' is greater than '01.03.2017' although the date is older. This is, because the string comparison compares character by character, starting with the first one:

- The first character of `21.01.2017` => `2`
- The first character of `01.03.2017` => `0`

And 0 is smaller than 2 (even in Unicode, Latin1, ASCII, whatever your charset and collation is).

This is by the way the reason, that the ISO date format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`. With this format, you comare the most significant parts first and compare by descending importance even when using the string representation.

If you really want to eliminate the seconds, I suggest to reduce the value by that amount:

```sql
 WHERE scheduledtime - interval second(scheduledtime) second <= cast('2017-03-13 08:30:00' as datetime)
```

Comment: Thanks Psi. I will just stick to 

WHERE scheduledtime <= currentDateTime - I think that's fine in the end.

Comment: Otherwise you can decrease the time by the `seconds` part: `datevalue - interval second(datevalue) second` which eliminates the seconds. I added an example to my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
SELECT * FROM fp_mail_reminder
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(scheduledtime, '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i') <= DATE_FORMAT('2017-03-13 08:30:00', '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i')
AND active = 1
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: That's already stated in the question, he wanted to know _why_, not how to fix it

Comment: Ahh! I see! Thank you @Psi